# Using PostgreSQL aggregate expressions in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

As of PostgreSQL 9.0+, using [aggregate expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) is supported. For example, you are able to use `ORDER BY` to sort rows before calling on to the PostGIS function `ST_MakeLine` as below:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(position ORDER BY timestamp)::bytea AS line
FROM recorded_positions
WHERE dataset_id = 98
```

What I have in my application is the following in an attempt to do this but clearly this is not the use case for `order_by()`:

```
queryset = queryset.order_by('timestamp') \
        .annotate(line=Func('position', function='ST_MakeLine')) \
        .values('line')
```

Of course this produces the following wrong SQL for what I want (and invalid due to use of `order_by` on a non aggregate column):

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(position)::bytea AS line
FROM recorded_positions
WHERE dataset_id = 98
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Is this possible at all with Django or will I have to do something else (raw query, subquery, etc) to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try the following:

```
queryset = queryset \
    .annotate(line=Func('position', Value('ORDER BY timestamp'), function='ST_MakeLine', arg_joiner=' ')) \
    .values('line')
```

And this QuerySet should generate the right SQL query.

Also you can implement your own function class by inheriting from `Func`.